# Unable to query French DBpedia with an accent in resource IRI (Modèle)

Tags: utf-8, rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

On the French DBpedia endpoing, I am trying to search all pages using a particular infobox.  This is my query:

```
SELECT ?person WHERE {
  ?person <http://fr.dbpedia.org/property/wikiPageUsesTemplate> <http://fr.dbpedia.org/page/ModèleInfobox_Politicien>
} LIMIT 100
```

It finds no result, but there are many of them, e.g.,

- http://fr.dbpedia.org/page/Fran%C3%A7ois_Hollande

I suspect that the problem is due to the accent in the resource.  I have also tried with an url-encoded accent:

```
SELECT ?person WHERE {
  ?person <http://fr.dbpedia.org/property/wikiPageUsesTemplate> <http://fr.dbpedia.org/page/Mod%C3%A8leInfobox_Politicien>
} LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 4):

The URI has a colon in it between Modèle and Infobox.  You query should be

```
select ?person where {
  ?person prop-fr:wikiPageUsesTemplate <http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Modèle:Infobox_Politicien>
}
limit 100
```

[SPARQL results](http://fr.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=select%20%3Fperson%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20prop-fr%3AwikiPageUsesTemplate%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Ffr.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FMod%C3%A8le%3AInfobox_Politicien%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)